# SubConverterFileIOException - music 21 show()

Tags: python, spyder, music21

I just installed music21, and I'm trying to get started on it. I have Musescore3 installed, but I can't make the show() funcion work.

I've tried changing the paths, following some instructions I found online, but to no avail

```py
from music21 import *

us = environment.UserSettings()
us['musicxmlPath'] = 'D:\\Program Files\\MuseScore 3\\bin\\Musescore3.exe'
us['musicxmlPath'] = 'D:\\Program Files\\MuseScore 3\\bin\\Musescore3.exe'
```

I'm trying to do a simple show()

```py
from music21 import *

f = note.Note('F5')
f.show()
```

Here's the error I got:

```py
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('D:/Users/Pedro/Pedro/Projeto Python-Música/music21test.py', wdir='D:/Users/Pedro/Pedro/Projeto Python-Música')
D:\Program Files\MuseScore 3\bin\Musescore3.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-19e1672511d4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Users/Pedro/Pedro/Projeto Python-Música/music21test.py', wdir='D:/Users/Pedro/Pedro/Projeto Python-Música')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Users/Pedro/Pedro/Projeto Python-Música/music21test.py", line 14, in <module>
    f.show()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\music21\base.py", line 2580, in show
    **keywords)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 360, in show
    subformats=helperSubformats, **keywords)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 938, in write
    fp = self.runThroughMusescore(fp, subformats, **keywords)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 895, in runThroughMusescore
    return self.findPNGfpFromXMLfp(fpOut)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 807, in findPNGfpFromXMLfp
    "png file of xml not found. Or file >999 pages?")

SubConverterFileIOException: png file of xml not found. Or file >999 pages?
```

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this situation, Because you can't use Musscore3 when you run on jupyter.
Try run with terminal it can work

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are errors when there is a space in the path -- try renaming your folder "Projeto Python-Música" to just "Python-Musica" (also removing accent to make sure unicode isn't the problem) and see if it solves things.